# mock build fails with "sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory" even though file exists

Tags: linux, centos-7, rpm, lxc

I'm trying to install tornado using mock, from the source rpm, in a Centos 7 lxc container:

```
mock -r epel-7-x86_64 python-tornado-4.4.2-3.fc26.src.rpm
```

Everything seems to go well until it stops with the error below. I've checked that the file exists:

```
# which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

Here's the full error:

```
Finish: chroot init
Start: build phase for python-tornado-4.4.2-3.fc26.src.rpm
Start: build setup for python-tornado-4.4.2-3.fc26.src.rpm
sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory
Building target platforms: x86_64
Building for target x86_64
Wrote: /builddir/build/SRPMS/python-tornado-4.4.2-3.el7.centos.src.rpm
Getting requirements for python-tornado-4.4.2-3.el7.centos.src
 --> python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
 --> python2-backports_abc-0.5-1.el7.noarch
 --> python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-4.el7.noarch
Error: No Package found for python2-singledispatch
ERROR: Exception(/root/share/python-tornado-4.4.2-3.fc26.src.rpm) Config(epel-7-x86_64) 0 minutes 25 seconds
INFO: Results and/or logs in: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64/result
ERROR: Command failed: 
 # /usr/bin/yum-builddep --installroot /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64/root/ --releasever 7 /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64/root//builddir/build/SRPMS/python-tornado-4.4.2-3.el7.centos.src.rpm --setopt=tsflags=nocontexts
Getting requirements for python-tornado-4.4.2-3.el7.centos.src
 --> python-devel-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
 --> python2-backports_abc-0.5-1.el7.noarch
 --> python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-4.el7.noarch
Error: No Package found for python2-singledispatch

This the output of build.log:

Mock Version: 1.3.3
ENTER ['do'](['bash', '--login', '-c', '/usr/bin/rpmbuild -bs --target x86_64 --nodeps /builddir/build/SPECS/python-tornado.spec'], chrootPath='/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64/root'shell=FalseprintOutput=Trueenv={'LANG': 'en_IE.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'PROMPT_COMMAND': 'printf "\\033]0;<mock-chroot>\\007"', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'PS1': '<mock-chroot> \\s-\\v\\$ '}gid=135user='mockbuild'timeout=0logger=<mockbuild.trace_decorator.getLog object at 0x1212a50>uid=0)
Executing command: ['bash', '--login', '-c', '/usr/bin/rpmbuild -bs --target x86_64 --nodeps /builddir/build/SPECS/python-tornado.spec'] with env {'LANG': 'en_IE.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'PROMPT_COMMAND': 'printf "\\033]0;<mock-chroot>\\007"', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'PS1': '<mock-chroot> \\s-\\v\\$ '} and shell False
sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory
Building target platforms: x86_64
Building for target x86_64
Wrote: /builddir/build/SRPMS/python-tornado-4.4.2-3.el7.centos.src.rpm
Child return code was: 0
```

Any idea why it can't find python2? Or is the error actually something else entirely? Thank you!

```
rpm -qa | grep python-singledispatch
python-singledispatch-3.4.0.2-2.el7.noarch
```

Comment: what's the output of `rpm -qa | grep python-singledispatch`?

Comment: Nothing. I just did yum install python-singledispatch then tried again, same error.

Comment: ok but you don't get `Error: No Package found for python2-singledispatch` - what's the next error you receive?

Comment: I still get `Error: No Package found for python2-singledispatch` as in the description

Comment: epel-7-x86_64 python-tornado-4.4.2-3.fc26.src.rpm - fc26 stands for fedora - is there a package for CentOS you could use?

Comment: The only one I found is python-tornado-2.2.1-8.el7.src.rpm which is an older version, but it works. I must have version >= 4.4.2 though. I guess there's no solution here until I can get a centos specific source rpm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in the comments. Just to complete it, found the correct tornado source rpm for CentOS 7 from https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/python34-tornado-4.4.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html. The one that gave the error was for Fedora (the site I had used previously didn't have one for CentOS).

So now, this works:

```
mock -r epel-7-x86_64 python3-tornado-4.4.2-1.el7.src.rpm
```

The error message was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

- `sh: /usr/bin/python2: No such file or directory`

This is just a warning and isn't stopping the execution.  It's caused when a spec file macro is attempting to run a python command prior to python getting installed in the mock chroot.

- `Error: No Package found for python2-singledispatch`

This is the actual problem.  Fedora has changed it's Python packaging policy since EL7.  Basically, you now have python2-$x and python3-$x versions of packages, and the unversioned python-$x name is provided by the python2-$x package.  At some point in the future this will be changed and python3-$x will provide python-$x.  The F26 tornado spec file had a requirement of python2-singledispatch, which isn't provided by anything in EL7.  One solution that could be suggested to the Fedora maintainer is to wrap the "2" in a conditional that only expands on Fedora, like this: `python%{?fedora:2}-singledispatch`.  That would expand to python2-singledispatch on Fedora, but python-singledispatch on CentOS, which is the desired behavior.